# Networking Mac OS X 10.6 and Vista via ethernet?

Tags: macos, windows-vista, networking, file-transfer, crossover

How can I make Vista home premium access OS X hard drive? and the other way around? I'd like to transfer files via direct ethernet.

Plugging in an ethernet cable makes both computers recognize a network, but not the other device. Each firewall is turned off, but no luck.

**Edit:**  I don't see Windows Sharing in the Service Column.

**Edit 2:** I called Apple (unbeatable support, by the way...) and the support agent walked me through it. Windows Vista was not behaving, so I booted into Windows 7. I'd love to get Vista working though...

Comment: Regarding your edit: That article was out of date. It's called just "File Sharing" now, and then you have to hit an "Options..." button and check an "SMB (Windows)" checkbox.

Comment: you should check this one http://superuser.com/questions/124421/some-networking-questions-with-airport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate Windows File Sharing on the mac under "Sharing" in "System Preferences" and grant a user of the Mac access to connect via Windows File Sharing. The basic steps (from Apple's site) are:

1. From the Apple menu, choose System
   Preferences.
2. From the View menu,
   choose Sharing. The Bonjour
   (formerly "Rendezvous") Name field
   will be used for the Mac OS X SMB
   host name. This is the name that
   appears in the Windows Network
   Neighborhood.

   For versions 10.2 and 10.2.1 only:
   If a DNS reverse lookup entry exists
   for your computer, the DNS name will
   be used instead of the one entered
   here.
3. Check the checkbox for the "File Sharing" service (in the Service column), and then hit the "Options..." button, and then, in the sheet that slides down, check the checkbox for "SMB (Windows)".

Thanks to Spiff for the edited #3 step.

For the full reference, see: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1812

Comment: That article is suffering from trying to use a single description to describe a process that has changed in many small ways each step between 10.2 and 10.6.

In 10.5 and 10.6, for Step 3, it should say to check the checkbox for the "File Sharing" service (in the Service column), and then hit the "Options..." button, and then, in the sheet that slides down, check the checkbox for "SMB (Windows)".

Comment: @Spiff -- Good point. Thanks for mentioning that. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a crossover cable.

After that, you should be able to set up a "Network Drive" or FTP server which will do the trick.

Comment: what is a crossover cable? RJ-45?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

Comment: As a longtime networking guy and longtime Mac user, it's strange to realize this, but many of my fellow Mac users don't know what crossover cables are anymore, because all Macs since the Titanium PowerBook G4 in early 2001 have had auto-crossover (a.k.a. auto MDI-X) PHYs.

Comment: @Spiff - Lol, I've "been a PC" for over 15 years. This is my first Mac. I'm a tech-hobbyist and I've heard the term. Networking is not my favorite area though... Thanks again.